# On Windows in python, possibly using the Outlook API, how can I get the full name of a user from their smaller login name?

Tags: python, windows, outlook, pywin32

At work, we have short login names, e.g. `hastingsg`, but Outlook and I believe other parts of the Windows system also have access to a longer name, e.g. Jeff Hastings.

In cpython (not IronPython), if I have the shorter login name, how can I get the longer full name?  I have [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) and [ExchangeCDO](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/945835) installed.

Answer (score 2):

Via the COM parts of `pywin32`, you need to get Outlook's Application object, and from it its attribute `Session`, which gives you the [Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176693.aspx) object (the `GetNamespace` method should also work for the same purpose, when called with the only supported argument value, `'MAPI'`).  From there you can use the `Accounts` property to get the [Accounts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176622.aspx) object, which is a typical COM collection -- indexable via `Item` up to its `Count`.  You loop over it and check each [Account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176620.aspx) object: each has two properties of interest -- a `UserName` (the string you want to check for equality to the "shorter login name") and a `DisplayName` -- the string you desire.

Yes, this is incredibly long and convoluted, but, that's par for the course for the COM interfaces that MS applications offer.  For all I know there might be leaner way in recent Outlook releases -- this is the long and gnarled way that's been working for a long time (these days I don't even have a Windows install handy to check this out and write the Python for you...!-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can query your Exchange Server Active Directory with a [dedicated module](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/active_directory.html)

(not tested):

```
import active_directory
user = active_directory.find_user("hastingsg")
print user.displayName
```

Comment: That gave me a result of 'hastingsg' again, but when I looked at the other properties, user.geco gave me something like what I want.

Thanks!

Comment: fyi... user.geco could be a corporate setting which is unique to my setup.

Comment: ooops.  it was user.gecos not user.geco

Answer (score 0):

May be you need TranslateName api e.g. play with something like this, 2ns /3rd argument can be constants from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724268(VS.85).aspx

```
win32security.TranslateName(win32api.GetUserName(), win32api.NameUnknown, win32api.NameDisplay)
```

or

```
win32net.NetUseGetInfo(win32api.GetComputerName(),win32api.GetUserName())
```

Comment: The first code returned the original user name and the second errored with: pywintypes.error: (2250, 'NetUseGetInfo', 'The network connection could not be found.')

Comment: in first you can try different 3rd argument e.g. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724268(VS.85).aspx